# Matrices Problem with 3 Unknown Variables J, K and M

Tags: algebra-precalculus, matrices, determinant

Given: $$
\left[\matrix{1&3 \\-2&4 }\right]+ \left[\matrix{11&5 \\-6&12 }\right]=K\left(\left[\matrix{3&2 \\J&M }\right]\right)
$$ Find the value of $J+K+M.$

the answer is $6$ (Multiple Choice)

My Solution:

I simplified the equation to:

$172 = K\left(3M-2J\right)$

what now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify the equation and get
$\pmatrix{12 & 8 \\ -8 & 16 }=\pmatrix{3K & 2K \\ KJ & KM }$.

This gives us: $3K=12$ and $2K=8$, thus $K=4$.

Also: $KJ=-8$, so $J=-8/K=-2$. And $KM=16$, so $M=16/K=4$.
Thus $J+K+M=-2+4+4=6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: By comparing the $(1,1)$-th entry on both sides of your matrix equation, you can get the value of $K$. Then, by comparing the bottom rows of both sides, you can solve for $J$ and $M$.